# jquery validation is not working properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net

I am new with Jquery.

By googling i have done following code which is not working.

I have txtLogin textbox and btnLogIn button.

I am trying simple thing.
If this textbox is expty then error message should get displayed in lblLoginError.

**Following is the code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#btnLogIn').click(function () {
             var LoginId = $("#txtLogin").val();
             if ($("#txtLogin").val() == "") {

                 $("#lblLoginError").text("Please Enter Login Id");

                 return false;
             }
             else {
                 $("#lblLoginError").text("");
                 return true;
             }

         });
     });
```

My problem is>> First time when textbox is empty and i click on button it gives me error message on lable[Its working fine according to code].

Second time when i enters any thing in textbox and press button then its removing error message.[This is also fine according to code].

But Third time when i removes the entered text and then presses the button , then it does not shows me error message.

*Note: I am using .NET In that AJAX UPDATE Panel. Page does not gets refreshed each time.
What can be problem?

Comment: @PSR : have you tried third time case?

Comment: yes i tried.Create a link in jsFiddle with your code

Comment: I have to refresh the page for third time case

Comment: without refreshing it is working for me

Comment: @PSR will you provide link?

Comment: looks fine at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uLNGb/

Comment: @ArunPJohny when we press the button the page automatically gets postback. Thats why its working on the link you provided. I have used Ajax Update Panel. Hence page is not getting refreshed.

Comment: @PSR when we press the button the page automatically gets postback. Thats why its working on the link you provided. I have used Ajax Update Panel. Hence page is not getting refreshed.

Comment: can u show the complete code

Comment: @PSR Compleate HTML Script?

Comment: you are saying ajax updated panel .

Comment: @PSR yes, AJAX Update panel. for page, not to be refreshed each time.

Comment: can u use jQuery validation for your validation

Comment: means ready made API?

Comment: i ma new with Jquery, so will you please post helpful link regarding jquery validation? plz..

Comment: Which version of Jquery are you using? How is it included? Which browser are you testing in?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   MOZILLA browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is very [useful](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)  link for jQuery validation

Example:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#commentForm").validate();
});
</script>

<form id="commentForm">
  <input type="text" id="txtLogin" class="required"/>
  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Here you can just apply class as required.

Comment: Thanks, i am going through it.

Comment: please mark it as answer if you got the solution with this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way, May be some space char left 3rd time, so best way to do this is here:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
         $('#btnLogIn').click(function () {
             var LoginId = $("#txtLogin").val();
             if ($("#txtLogin").val().trim() == "") {

                 alert($("#txtLogin").val());
                 $("#lblLoginError").text("Please Enter Login Id");

                 return false;
             }
             else {
                 $("#lblLoginError").text("");
                 return true;
             }

         });
     });
</script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type='text' id='txtLogin' />
  <input type='button' id='btnLogIn' value="Sign In"/>
  <p id='lblLoginError'></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Notice the  `if ($("#txtLogin").val().trim() == "")`, `trim()` will eliminate space char.\

Here is live URL to it: http://jsbin.com/igoceg/2/edit

I hope this help, let me know if problem still there.

Comment: Yeah, It will work fine on the link. My real problem is that, since i am using Ajax update panel, page does not gets refreshed each time. On the link you provided, when i presses the button , page gets refreshed , thats why it works

Comment: Ok, now I have created it in local file, this time it is not refreshing, I am updating the code, you can copy it and save it as .html then check on machine, see if this works fine.